# C++ re-throw an exception caught by 

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

how can I re-throw an exception caught by

```
catch(...)
```

block?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`throw` with no operand rethrows the "current exception".

Answer (score 15):

This is how.

```
catch(...)
{
    throw;
}
```